# How to copy the next item on List to the clipboard using Python?

Tags: python, keyboard

```
import keyboard
import pyperclip
instance = 0 
A = [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6, 7 , 8 , 9, 10]
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl+v'):
        x = A[instance]
        pyperclip.copy(x)
        pyperclip.paste()
        instance += 1
        print(pyperclip.paste()) #Just to see which item is currently on the clipboard
```

Here is the code.
I want each of the item on the list A to be copied to the clipboard after I click "ctrl+v".
On first trigger I want the next item to be copied to the clipboard, but the code run through all the items.
What can be done so each items are copied only on the trigger

Comment: There are no tuples in your code.

Comment: sorry, I meant the List A